# Как сделать код, чтобы он считал квадратные уравнения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Чтобы бот ,заносил данные в переменную, делал действие и считал корень и дискриминант по кнопке в бота(делаю что-то наподобие калькуляторе). Как сделать такой код? То есть первое число в одну переменную, второе в о вторую и третье в третью.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно можно сделать 3 переменные для a,b,c. Сначала человек вписывает в перменную a значения, потом в b и так далее. Дальше остается правильно написать код, чтобы он мог правильно посчитать.

Comment: да вот я и искал такой код и пыталася сам сделать,но ничего не выходило

Comment: Ну так отправь этот код сюда, помогут